# How to get mongodb database base name after connection in nodejs?

Tags: mongodb

I found that the latest version of MongoDB nodejs driver introduced `MongoClient` class which is the first class instance I can get after making a connection. But it doesn't provide a default database instance. Below is the source code.

```
MongoClient.connect(url, (err, client) => {
    if(err) {
      return null;
    }
    client.db('test');  // how can I know the database name? Do I need to parse the url?
  });
```

The above code shows how to get the mongo client instance after connection. I need to call `client.db` to get the database instance. My question is how I know the default database name in the `client` instance. All I get is the connection `url`. Do I need to parse the connection url in order to get the connected database which is `test` in the above example?

I know there is a method `db.getName()` returnes the database name. But how can I get the `db` instance without parsing the URL to get the database name from the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of MongoDB 4.4 this seems to have changed. You can access the current database name through the databaseName property:

```
const client = await MongoClient.connect(DB_HOST, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
db = client.db(DB_NAME);
console.log(db.databaseName);
```

Answer (score 5):

In current `mongodb` driver.  The `Db` class instance has `databaseName` property.  So getting database name that `MongoClient` was initialized is simply

```
const db = mongoClient.db();
const dbName = db.databaseName;
```

[Nodejs driver Db documentation](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.5/api/Db.html)

Comment: This is the right answer in the context of nodeJS with mongodb package.

Answer (score 0):

change your code as below

```
let db = null;
MongoClient.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', (err, client) => {
    if(err) {
      return null;
    }
    db = client.db('test');
  });
```

> use db.getName();

or change config as below

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient
  , Server = require('mongodb').Server;

    var mongoClient = new MongoClient(new Server('localhost', 27017));
    mongoClient.open(function(err, mongoClient) {
      var db1 = mongoClient.db("mydb");

      mongoClient.close();
    });
```

[refer to documentation](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html)

Comment: Does this mean I need to parse my connection url in order to get the database name `mydb`?

Comment: nope. It's a method to get database name you have connected.

Comment: I know the `db.getName()` returnes the database name. But how can I get the `db` instance without parsing the database name?

Comment: To connect to mongoose you must know the db name in advance. using that db name you can create db instance as `var db1 = mongoClient.db("mydb");`

Comment: In your case you can parse this url `mongodb://localhost:27017/test`

Comment: My original through is that why we have to parse the URL if we already provide the database in the URL. I don't think the driver API upgrade makes sense in this case. At least it should provide a `client.db()` return the default database from the connection.

Answer (score 0):

The database name exists inside the `client` returned from the connection:

```
db = client.db(client.s.options.dbName);
```

<sub>Verified in version 3.2</sub>

I couldn't find anything related in the documentation, so not sure if it's accessible from any version of MongoDB driver or if it will change in future versions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using the following:

```
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient; // mongodb@3.1.4
const client = await MongoClient.connect(...);
const stats = await client.stats();
const dbName = stats.db;
```

The name of the database is in the stats object.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.